# How to reorder the results on Plot_composition Microbiome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a plot composition with different phylum with a category Other like this :

```
pseq <- Merge_Final_pourcent %>% aggregate_taxa(level = "Phylum")
ps1.com.fam <- microbiome::aggregate_top_taxa(pseq, "Phylum", top = 11)
ps1.com.fam.rel <- microbiome::transform(ps1.com.fam, "compositional")

svg(file="phylum.svg")
plot_composition(ps1.com.fam.rel) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_brewer("Phylum", palette = "Paired") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  ggtitle("Relative abundance") + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 18))
dev.off()
```

I try to go down the category Other :
So I try to change my phyloseq and convert only the name other by Z_other but it deseappear from the phyloseq object and from the plot too:

```
essai<-as.data.frame(tax_table(ps1.com.fam.rel))

essai$unique <- sub("Other", "Z_Other", essai$unique)
essai$Phylum <- sub("Other", "Z_Other", essai$Phylum)
rownames(essai) <- sub("Other", "Z_Other", rownames(essai))
tax_table(ps1.com.fam.rel) <- as.matrix(essai)


essai<-as.data.frame(otu_table(ps1.com.fam.rel))
rownames(otu_table(ps1.com.fam.rel)) <- sub("Other", "Z_Other", rownames(otu_table(ps1.com.fam.rel)))
otu_table(ps1.com.fam.rel) <- as.matrix(essai)

svg(file="0_1phylum_BMP.svg")
plot_composition(ps1.com.fam.rel) + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_brewer("Phylum", palette = "Paired") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  ggtitle("Relative abundance") + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 18))
dev.off()
```

[image: THE RESULTS]

[image: THE EXPECTATIONS]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try to reorder the levels using `factor`.  Perhaps this might help.

```
  essainoo <- subset(essai, essai$Phylum!="Other")
  neworder <- c(unique(essainoo$Phylum),"Other")
  
  essai$Phylum <- factor(essai$Phylum, levels=neworder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late this answer, but maybe someone else can use it because it's the only forum I could find with this question.
I am not an R expert, and this way is only if you intend to generate a microbiome composition graph with top 20-30. It is super rudimentary, but it worked for me.
The order of the graph is that of the OTU table, so I simply reordered:

```
Phyloseq_object@otu_table[c(1,2,3,5,4),]
```

Where: -phyloseq_object is my phyloseq object,
-otu_table is by default that name
-c(1,2,3,5,4) my desired order.

Greetings!!!